# How to create csv export button with wordpress

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

Hi to all wordpress developers: Please help me on how to create button that will export csv. I create some functions below to output as csv but my problem right now is how to call this function with a button or  href. In wordpress way thanks.

```
function csv(){

    global $wpdb;

    $sql = "SELECT * from activity  WHERE activity_date = '2016-08-07' ";
    $MyQuery = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

// Process report request
 if (! $MyQuery) {
    $Error = $wpdb->print_error();
    die("The following error was found: $Error");

 } else {

    $csv_fields=array();
    $csv_fields[] = 'Activity Date';
    $csv_fields[] = 'Name';
    $csv_fields[] = 'Activity Name';
    $csv_fields[] = 'Email Address';
    $csv_fields[] = 'Phone No.';

    $output_filename = 'MyReport.csv';
    $output_handle = fopen( 'php://output', 'w' );

    header('Content-Disposition:attachment'); 
    header('Content-type: application/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$output_filename.'"' );

// Insert header row
    fputcsv( $output_handle, $csv_fields );

foreach ($MyQuery as $Result) {
    $leadArray = (array) $Result; // Cast the Object to an array
        fputcsv( $output_handle, $leadArray );
    }
  exit;
  }
}
```

Comment: did you try with ajax call?

Comment: Hi  vel, not yet so ajax will be the best way to do this? thanks

Comment: Yes. It is best way to do that.